# How to build a Siamese Network from Transformer Model? Shape Input Error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

I have the following Base Network with some important (error is coming due to these) parameters (please assume every else parameter)

```
maxlen = 250
model_dense = 256
```

Base Model :

```
def build_base_model(inputs):
  inputs = layers.Input(shape=(maxlen,),name='base_input')
  embedding_layer = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim)
  x = embedding_layer(inputs)
  transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, trans_drop1, trans_drop2, trans_reg1, trans_reg2)
  x = transformer_block(x)
  x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(x)
  x = layers.Dropout(model_drop1)(x)
  outputs = layers.Dense(model_dense)(x)
  base_model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
  return base_model
```

and I my `Siamese` network as:

```
base_model = build_base_model()
input_text1 = layers.Input(shape=(maxlen,))
input_text2 = layers.Input(shape=(maxlen,))

emb1 = base_model(input_text1)
emb2 = base_model(input_text2)

distance = layers.Lambda(euclidean_distance)([emb1, emb2])
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(distance)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[emb1, emb2], outputs=outputs)

model.compile(
    optimizer="adam", metrics = ["accuracy",], loss= 'binary_crossentropy')

history = model.fit(
    train_X, train_y, batch_size=batch_size, epochs = 50, validation_split = 0.15, callbacks = callbacks, verbose = 1,
)
```

It gives me an error as:

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "model_11" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 256), found shape=(None, 250)
```

What am I doing wrong?

1. [Base Transformer model tutorial taken from this](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/text_classification_with_transformer/)
2. [Siamese Model Structure, cosine distance, make_pairs from this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/11/30/siamese-networks-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/)

**UPDATE**- I have built the new network in a different manner and it is up and running. Can someone please confirms if it is the correct one:

```
inputs1 = layers.Input(shape=(maxlen,),name='inp_1')
inputs2 = layers.Input(shape=(maxlen,),name='inp_2')
embedding_layer = TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim)
transformer_block = TransformerBlock(embed_dim, num_heads, ff_dim, trans_drop1, trans_drop2, trans_reg1, trans_reg2)
pooling = layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()
drop_layer = layers.Dropout(model_drop1)
out_dense = layers.Dense(model_dense)

x1 = embedding_layer(inputs1)
x2 = embedding_layer(inputs2)

x1 = transformer_block(x1)
x2 = transformer_block(x2)

x1 = pooling(x1)
x2 = pooling(x2)


x1 = drop_layer(x1)
x2 = drop_layer(x2)

vec_x1 = out_dense(x1)
vec_x2 = out_dense(x2)


distance = layers.Lambda(euclidean_distance)([vec_x1, vec_x2])
outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(distance)
model = keras.Model(inputs=[inputs1, inputs2], outputs=outputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

in the line`model = keras.Model(inputs=[emb1, emb2], outputs=outputs)`:
I suspect that you are mean to say`model = keras.Model(inputs=[input_text1, input_text2], outputs=outputs)`